# NLog fails to open file on Windows with Mono

Tags: mono, servicestack, nlog

I have a small set of ServiceStack REST services that is using NLog 2.1 (from NuGet) for logging.

My test server is running:

- Windows 7
- IIS 7.5
- .NET 4.5
- NLog config:

```
<nlog throwExceptions="true" internalLogToConsole="true" internalLogLevel="Debug" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
        <target name="c" xsi:type="Console" />
        <target name="f1" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\logs\test.log" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" writeTo="c,f1" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

My NLog config is exceedingly simple... just trying to get it working... 
and in this configuration, everything works fine. NLog creates the log files correctly.

On my DEVELOPMENT machine, I am using:

- Windows 7
- Xamarin Studio / XSP4
- Mono 3.2.3

Here is my Application_Start...

```
protected void Application_Start() {
   LogManager.LogFactory = new NLogFactory();
   ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Global));
   log.Info("Application_Start called");

   try {
      new AppHost().Init();
   } catch (Exception e) {
      log.Error("Exception caught initializing AppHost");
   }
}
```

In this configuration, my service's AppHost().Init() throws an exception as ServiceStack is registering my services in ServiceController.cs. I believe that part is irrelevant except that it is the first time something is logged outside of Application_Start (because both of the calls in Application_Start work... the log.info *before* the exception and the log.error *after* the exception).

Here is the exception that is shown:

[image]

The most relevant bit is that there was a **System.NotImplementedException** thrown at NLog.Internal.FileAppenders.BaseFileAppender.WindowsCreateFile (System.String fileName, Boolean allowConcurrentWrite).

I have found a workaround (in the accepted answer below). Hopefully anyone else who runs into this will quickly come upon this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some digging around on Google led me to this NLog pull request:

**[Avoid Win32-specific file functions in Mono where parts not implemented.](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/219)**

It appears that this change tries to use the preprocessor to NOT call WindowsCreateFile at all. However, for some reason, this still executes.

So I then went to check the newest version of BaseFileAppender.cs in the NLog GitHub repository to make sure someone didn't at some later point break this again.

```
#if !NET_CF && !SILVERLIGHT && !MONO
    try
        {
            if (!this.CreateFileParameters.ForceManaged && PlatformDetector.IsDesktopWin32)
            {
                return this.WindowsCreateFile(this.FileName, allowConcurrentWrite);
            }
        }
        catch (SecurityException)
        {
            InternalLogger.Debug("Could not use native Windows create file, falling back to managed filestream");
        }
#endif
```

Hmmm... it's still there. What gives? Why doesn't MONO seem to be defined by the preprocessor, thus allowing this block to execute? I'm not sure. Before I started down that path of investigation, I noticed another change...

```
if (!this.CreateFileParameters.ForceManaged && ...
```

So after following that tracing that ForceManaged boolean back to it's origin, it appeared that I could set **forceManaged="true"** on my FileTarget declaration in my NLog config. Could it really be that simple?!

```
<nlog throwExceptions="true" internalLogToConsole="true" internalLogLevel="Debug" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
        <target name="c" xsi:type="Console" />
        <target name="f1" xsi:type="File" forceManaged="true" fileName="C:\logs\test.log" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" writeTo="c,f1" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Once that change was made, everything worked... the call to WindowsCreateFile that was throwing the exception was skipped & a managed filestream was used instead, which works great. Hallelujah!

Lastly, I could not find that forceManaged flag in the NLog documentation anywhere. Would likely have found this solution sooner if it was.

Comment: great, but if you're using Mono, you should avoid using Windows altogether, as its features on Windows are less and inferior (the point of Mono is to run .NET **outside** Windows anyway)

Comment: Sure, sure. But final decision hasn't been made as to whether the test & production servers are going to be Windows or Linux. And I don't have control over the OS on my _development_ machine unless I want to run something else in a VM. Aside from this, the only other issue I've run into has been [this one](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11817).

Comment: there have been recent improvements in that area recently, I would recommend you to test with mono master